# array de checkbox seleccionados con angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Saludos soy nuevo en angular agradezco su ayuda, tengo una lista de checkbox que traigo desde una base de datos, pero ahora necesito escoger los que se seleccionen y mandarlos en un array al backend pero no se como seria este proceso:

```
 <label class="inline-flex items-center mt-3" *ngFor="let categoria of categorias">
                        <input type="checkbox" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">{{categoria.name}}</span>
                      </label>
```

Comment: crea un método que reciba el id del checkbox como argumento cuando el usuario de click sobre el y los vas almacenando en un arreglo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

¡Hola! podrías crear un método en el controlador que reciba la categoría, y el evento del checkbox (si fue seleccionado o deseleccionado).

HTML

```
<label class="inline-flex items-center mt-3" *ngFor="let categoria of categorias">
                    <input type="checkbox" (change)="onCategoriaPressed(categoria,$event.target.checked)" class="form-checkbox h-5 w-5 text-indigo-600"><span class="ml-2 text-gray-700">{{categoria.name}}</span>
                  </label>
```

CONTROLLER (TS)

```
categoriaSelectedArray = [];
onCategoriaPressed(categoriaSelected: any, checked: boolean){
  if (checked) { //Si el elemento fue seleccionado
    //Agregamos la categoría seleccionada al arreglo de categorías seleccionadas
    this.categoriaSelectedArray.push(categoriaSelected);
  } else { //Si el elemento fue deseleccionado
    //Removemos la categoría seleccionada del arreglo de categorías seleccionadas
    this.categoriaSelectedArray.splice(this.categoriaSelectedArray.indexOf(categoriaSelected), 1);
  }
}
```